# return only values from the left column that do not exists in the right column. DO not need data matching with the right column

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I need to return only values from the Left column that do not exist in the Right column. Do not need the data matching with the right column.

I have two tables with the same metadata. Left table has 11137 records, Right table - 9725. (FYI, Left table has 8508 unique ID_pk; and Right table has - 7194 unique  ID_pk.) I only need to return all the rows from the left table that not in the Right table.

I've tried various joints and CTE, but it returns 94857 for just join or 96463 for the left join.

```
With CTE
AS
(Select * From ##GlobalTempTable_PW_2
Select CTE.ID_pk, CTE.[Dweling_fk], CTE.FieldID, CTE.House
From CTE Join ##GlobalTempTable_LA_2 LA on CTE.ID_pk = LA.ID_fk
);
```

I've also tried using NOT EXISTS, but not getting the desired result. May be I have a logic error.

Select * From ##GlobalTempTable_PW_2 PW 
Where NOT EXISTS
(
Select ID_fk From ##GlobalTempTable_PW_2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select PW.ID_fk From ##GlobalTempTable_PW_2 PW
Join ##GlobalTempTable_LA_2 LA on PW.ID_fk = LA.ID_fk);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is usually accomplished using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
Select * 
From ##GlobalTempTable_PW_2 PW
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ##GlobalTempTable_LA_2 LA 
                  WHERE PW.ID_pk = LA.ID_fk)
```

This query returns all the records of table `##GlobalTempTable_PW_2` that don't have a matching record in table `##GlobalTempTable_LA_2`.

Comment: Thanks, a lot. I did use the NOT EXISTS, but my logic was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this:

```
SELECT pw.*
FROM ##GlobalTempTable_PW_2 pw
LEFT JOIN ##GlobalTempTable_LA_2 la
ON pw.ID_pk = la.ID_fk
WHERE la.ID_fk IS NULL
```

FYI: use this approach only if you are joining tables by `UNIQUE` columns. Otherwise LEFT JOIN may dublicate some results

Comment: nowadays it is best to choice the **NOT EXISTS** solution, it is a bit faster, really optimized with a special (Anti Semi Join)

Comment: @MtwStark is it true for every database engine? (interested in Oracle and MySQL)

Comment: Oracle have this optimization for years, look at [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: Oracle](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/)

Comment: Also Postgres should, MySQL maybe depends on version.. but generally, I think nowadays you can use NOT EXISTS and LEFT JOIN the same way, the main difference is that with JOIN you can use the columns in your SELECT with NOT EXISTS you can't. 
Said that, the NOT IN syntax is my last choice.